# PHP array into one string

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have one array that is filled by mysql_query. Values that are in this array I want to put into one continuous string for example:

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

INSERT INTO 'new_slovmas'.'$tabulka'('$array[0]', '$array[1]', '$array[3]') 
       VALUES ('$r_1', '$r_2', '$r_3')";
```

Sense in one table is over 50 columns I do not want to fill it manually, but by WHILE or FOR. So I was thinking about putting values into one string like this:

```
$array = array("'1',", "'2',", "'3',", "'4',", "'5',");
```

so now I have this:

```
echo $array[2]; => '3',
```

By the cycle I wont to achieve having multiple entries in one variable.

```
$str = $array[0], $array[1] ... $array[xy];

INSERT INTO 'new_slovmas'.'$tabulka'('$str') 
       VALUES ('$r_1', '$r_2', '$r_3')";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`implode()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

```
$string = implode(',', array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5));  // $string = 1,2,3,4,5
```

Comment: ok, what about this array `$stlpec[] = $row['column_name'];` i do not know values in it. How it will look with function implode? It does not take `implode(',', $stlpec[$i]);`

Comment: Since arrays are not stored in database columns you would not actually be working with an array. You would need to determine what kind of data that is before you can actually plan to do anything with it.

Comment: well i already have data in array, but I do not know in witch form to write implode, i want something similar to this, but it is wrong `implode(',', $stlpec[$i]);`

Comment: That definitely means you are not passing an array to implode. Are you 100% sure you are working with an array?

Comment: when I type `echo $stlpec[1];` I get result

Comment: That means it is not an array. You would need to use `print_r()` to get the results of an array.

Comment: It is array it gave me result even with `print_r($stlpec)` this is result what I got: Array ( [0] => id [1] => question [2] => answer [3] => sequence [4] => active )

Comment: lol that simple :D I wanted do it through cycle this is simpler :) ... and one more question, how do I achieve to have it in form `'abc', 'def',.....` , now it is like this: `'id,question,answer,sequence,active',`

Comment: $String = "'" . implode("', '", $stlpec) . "'";

Answer (score 3):

PHP's implode function will unpack an array into a string for use in Javascript. Try this:

```
$str = implode(',',$array);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
join(",", $array);
```

Also, be sure to escape your values before you insert them into the database. You do this in case that one of your values has a single quote (') or something worse in it (like valid SQL), which would crash your query. You can use mysql_real_escape_string(...) or mysqli_real_escape_string(...) for this

Comment: `join()` is an alias of `implode()`